# SELECT para data com formato dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: mysql, data

**Consulta**

```
SELECT 
campo
FROM 
Tabela
WHERE data BETWEEN '2016-10-20' AND '2016-10-20'
```

`data` e um campo com tipo `datetime` ,estou com problemas com os registros por exemplo que possuem o seguinte valor :

```
2016-10-20 19:00:00
```

Datas com esse tipo de valor não aparecem na consulta.

Qual seria a forma de consulta apropriada para o formato `yyyy/MM/dd/ hh:mm:ss` ?   sendo que o usuario escolhe a penas a data incial e final no formato  `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: você quer filtrar o valores só com a data no formato brasileiro?

Comment: Coloquei errado no enunciado vou concertar malz =s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a função [Date()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date), que funciona mais ou menos como a `TRUNC()` do Oracle.

```
SELECT 
campo
FROM 
Tabela
WHERE Date(data) BETWEEN '2016-10-20' AND '2016-10-20'
```

Comment: Perfeito muito obrigado !